# HTML page printing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dynamic page that displays members information and their photos from a database. My problem is that when a user prints the page it sometimes cuts off a members information and prints the rest on the next page. Is there a way to force a page size or something that won't allow information to be spread over two pages? Maybe Javascript or CSS?

Comment: [Simple css page breaking for printouts](http://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks)

Answer (score 1):

If you enclose your member info and pictures inside a div or other block, you can use the page-break-inside CSS property similar to below.

#### HTML

```
<div class="member-info">
    ....
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.member-info {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

[MDN documentation for page-break-inside](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-inside)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a page for print with [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) feature `@media print`.

Comment: @Teemu he can set, what he want to print with `display: none`. Isn't it?

Comment: How would I know, this is your answer ; ).

Comment: @Teemu I just asked out of politeness, all of a sudden I'm wrong

Comment: Umh... Sounds a bit wrong way. Anyway, a good answer would explain how to solve the problem. Without an explanation, how to use Media Queries, _in the answer_ , it smells more like a link-only-answer.

Comment: @Teemu but he didn't provide any code, he simply asked the board how best to do it

Comment: Well, other answerers seem to have composed something (though not sure if any usefull). If you feel there's not enough information in the question, why not ask more in a comment instead of answering?

Comment: @Teemu I thought if it did not provide any code at all, he does not example, just advice

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS and media queries to style your page when it's being printed.

It would look something like this (I don't know how your exact HTML looks):

```
@media print {
  body {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

You can read more about it here:

https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/tips-and-tricks-for-print-style-sheets/

Answer (score 0):

Nice and simple!

```
@media screen {
  body {
    width: 75%;
  }
}

@media print {
  body {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

For a deeper study: [CSS Media Queries & Using Available Space](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) and [Use CSS media queries for responsiveness](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en)